# Evenly spaced grids with vertical measure

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I have the following code to create three grids in tikz.

- I'd like to indicate to the side of the first grid with a double headed arrow what is the height of the grid which is supposed to be $2^{Q(n)+\lceil \log_2(s) \rceil}$.
- I would also like to space these three grids evenly, so that the space is the same between all of them.

The expected result is shown in the picture below. The dots in the middle of the tables are not essential.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, y=-1cm]
\draw[xstep=1,ystep=-1] (0,8) grid (3,0);
\node[label=$q_1$] at (0.5,0.15) {};
\node[label=$\ldots$] at (1.5,0.15) {};
\node[label=$q_s$] at (2.5,0.15) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, y=-1cm]
\draw[xstep=1,ystep=-1] (0,8) grid (5,0);
\node[label=$c_1$] at (0.5,0.15) {};
\node[label=$\ldots$] at (1.5,0.15) {};
\node[label=$\ldots$] at (2.5,0.15) {};
\node[label=$\ldots$] at (3.5,0.15) {};
\node[label=$c_{Q(n)}$] at (4.5,0.15) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, y=-1cm]
\draw[xstep=1,ystep=-1] (0,8) grid (5,0);
\node[label=$d_1$] at (0.5,0.15) {};
\node[label=$\ldots$] at (1.5,0.15) {};
\node[label=$\ldots$] at (2.5,0.15) {};
\node[label=$\ldots$] at (3.5,0.15) {};
\node[label=$d_{Q(n)}$] at (4.5,0.15) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) next time. Here is working example with report document class. I tweaked the label drawing on top of the grid a little bit to put them in one single node. This way the format looks more consistent. I added the arrows on the left and put the label in 90 degree. So, it won't took too much horizontal space. Hope this is what you want.

> Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{showframe} % show the margin boundary
\usepackage{lipsum} % Create dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, y=-1cm]
\draw[xstep=1,ystep=-1] (0,8) grid (3,0);
\node [anchor=south west] at (0,0) {$q_1~\ldots~q_s$};
\draw (-0.5,0) -- (-1.2,0); %top rule
\draw (-0.5,8) -- (-1.2,8); %bottom rule
\draw [latex-latex] (-1,0) --node[rotate=90,above] {$2^{Q(n)+\lceil \log_2(s) \rceil}$} (-1,8); %arrows and label in 90 degree
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, y=-1cm]
\draw[xstep=1,ystep=-1] (0,8) grid (5,0);
\node[anchor=south west] at (0,0) {$c_1~\ldots\ldots\ldots~c_{Q(n)}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, y=-1cm]
\draw[xstep=1,ystep=-1] (0,8) grid (5,0);
\node[anchor=south west] at (0,0) {$d_1~\ldots\ldots\ldots~d_{Q(n)}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> Output:
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting all three grids in one picture to ensure good alignment.

I made a new node style called `mygrid` to make grid placement easier. The style draws the node and adds the grid as a `path picture`. Also, there's a style `block` to cover the grid with dots.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    block/.style={fill=white, minimum width=2.1cm, minimum height=2.1cm, inner sep=0pt, path picture={\draw[very thick, loosely dotted](path picture bounding box.east)--(path picture bounding box.west);}},
    mygrid/.style={draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=6cm, path picture={\draw[step=.5](path picture bounding box.south east)grid(path picture bounding box.north west); \node[fill=white, minimum width=2.1cm, minimum height=2.1cm]{};}}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node[mygrid, label=above:$g_0\quad\dots\quad g_s$](A){}; \node[block]{};
\node[mygrid, right=of A, label=above:$\quad c_1\ \ \dots\ c_{Q(n)}$](B){}; \node[block] at (B){};
\node[mygrid, right=of B, label=above:$\quad d_1\ \ \dots\ d_{Q(n)}$](C){}; \node[block] at (C){};
\draw[<->] ([xshift=-5mm]A.south west)--node[above, sloped]{$2^{Q(n)+\lceil \log_2(s) \rceil}$}([xshift=-5mm]A.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```